# Is the Bray-Curtis dissimilarity/similarity independent of richness/diversity?

Tags: independence, distance, diversity, jaccard-similarity

I was told about potential issues with the Bray-Curtis dissimilarity/similarity measure. Specifically, I have been asked if Bray-Curtis is independent of richness/diversity. I am unsure how to answer and I have been unsuccessful in locating any information on this topic.

Insights would be very welcome.

Comment: BC measures dissimilarity between two sites, while each site will have it's own richness/diversity. The two are related of course. Why is that a potential issue? Maybe you could edit/expand your question a bit?

Comment: if you're up for a dive into the deep end on this, I highly recommend Chao and Chiu 2016 Methods in Ecology and Evolution https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12551